# Filtering output by service and ip

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to Parse an NMAP output file to display specific strings in a terminal.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for y in $(cat out.txt | grep -E 'tcp*open' | awk '{print$2}' | sort | uniq)
do
        echo "$y"
        for z in $(cat out.txt | grep -E "(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} | awk '{print$NF}')
              echo "$z"      
        done
done
```

Does this work?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just asking nmap for an easier-to-parse output format? It supports both JSON (which you can query with `jq`) and XML (which you can query with XPath or XQuery or XSLT-based tools like XMLStarlet), after all.

Comment: BTW, see [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...nmap also supports `-oG`, which is explicitly intended to be easy to parse with standard shell tools. Using an output format explicitly meant for human consumption when your actual consumer is a script is pretty much indefensible.

Comment: (Also, `grep | awk` is pretty much always an antipattern -- you can put a regex into the awk expression itself: `awk '/regex/ { block }'` will only run `block` for code that matches `regex`).

Comment: You can also do the majority of the difficult work with the (included) [reverse-index](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/reverse-index.html) NSE script. It lists each port on a line with a list of IPs that have that port open. I think I'll expand it tonight to optionally index on service name instead of port number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if it had to be bash, so I did bash and awk:

Awk :-

```
awk '/Nmap/{ip = $NF}$2 == "open"{type[$NF][i++] = ip}
     END{for(n in type){print n RT "===============";
           for(i in type[n])print type[n][i];print RT}}' input_file
```

Bash :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A type

#set -xv
while read -ra array
do
    [[ -z "${array[0]}" ]] && continue

    [[ "${array[0]}" == Nmap ]] && ip=${array[-1]}

    [[ "${array[1]}" == open ]] && type[${array[-1]}]+=" $ip"
done<input_file

for t in "${!type[@]}"
do
    echo -e "$t\\n==============="
    for i in ${type[$t]}
    do
        echo "$i"
    done
    echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First I tried to modify your code but it looks awful.
Just using bash function, I would say instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash

while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^Nmap\ scan\ report\ for\ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ ]]; then
        ip=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]+/(tcp|udp)\ +[^\ ]+\ +([^\ ]+) ]]; then
        proto=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        if [ -x ${hash[$proto]} ]; then
            hash[$proto]=$ip
        else
            hash[$proto]="${hash[$proto]},$ip"
        fi
    fi
done < NMAP_all_hosts.txt

for proto in ${!hash[@]}; do
    echo $proto
    echo ============
    IFS=','
    for ip in ${hash[$proto]}; do
        echo $ip
    done
    echo
done
```